# The ActiveRecord method offset is not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working in a new code base and can't figure out why there is an arbitrary limit being set on the query, which prevents the `offset` method from working correctly.

- mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
- Rails 6.0

```
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.1)
[1] pry(main)> UserAccount.offset(1).last
   (1.9ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
  UserAccount Load (6.0ms)  SELECT `user_accounts`.* FROM `user_accounts` LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 1
```

Currently, `UserAccount.offset(n).last` is returning the last record.

```
irb(main):001:0> UserAccount.offset(1).last == UserAccount.last
=> true
```

Comment: You're not specifying an order so your offset and limit are pretty much meaningless. And generally, offset and limit go together so maybe ActiveRecord is defaulting the limit to `2**64 - 1` (i.e. the maximum unsigned long). I'd expect `UserAccount.offset(1).last == UserAccount.last` to be true pretty much always anyway; `UserAccount.offset(1).last` is saying "start with all the user accounts, skip the first one, then give me the last one from what's left" and that will almost always be the same as "give me the last user account".

Comment: What is this code meant to achieve?

Comment: I also experience the same bug. The first comment here doesn't make sense. The `last` supposed to add limit and order. `offset` should only add `OFFSET` to SQL on top of what `last` already added.

Comment: As a workaround it of course works to just do `offset(n).order(id: :desc).first` but it's ugly and nobody will remember to do it all the time.